# Magento 2: Adding a color picker as an attribute to a product form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

[image]

Please tell me how you can add a color picker as an attribute to the product form.
I tried several options from the Internet, well, they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

use this [library](https://jscolor.com/jscolor.com/download/) and load that library in the product details page like

`app/code/Vendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <script src="Vendor_YourModule::js/jscolor.min.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

and on created attribute add frontend class like

`biztech_color_picker jscolor {width:243, height:150, position:'buttom', borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#514943',hash:true}`

this will convert it to the color picker

If this does not work you can simply modify the product_edit form using

`ModifyMeta()` method which is responsible to provide the ui data for building a form

you can replace your attribute with the [ui colorpicker](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-colorpicker.html)

create a file in

`app/code/Vendor/YourModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="addColorPicker" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ColorConfig</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Now create class `ColorPickerConfig.php` add method you can refer from [Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize-modifier-class.html) and replace your attribute config with the colorPicker of UI config.