# Magento 2 : How to add product attribute as color picker in product form?

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, product-attribute

**I'm trying to add color picker attribute in product form**

I have referred this link:- https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-a-color-picker-in-product-edit-form-in-magento-2/?unapproved=1745&moderation-hash=3ee404bde1e2041476b04e80ed232540#comment-1745

> But i'm getting `Undefined index: container_[attribute_code]` in my
> case `my_color`. I'm adding attribute using data patch. I'm adding my
> files below,

**Also making changes according this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323055/73212**

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="addColorPicker" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\Modifier\Product\Style</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Ui/Modifier/Product/Style.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Modifier\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

class Style extends AbstractModifier
{
   public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
   {
       // Color attribute
        $code = 'my_color';

        $meta['product-details']['children']['container_' . $code]['children'] = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_' . $code]['children'], [
            $code => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'colorPicker' => [
                            'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/form/element/pickcolors'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]); 
       return $meta;
   }

   public function modifyData(array $data)
   {
       return $data;
   }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/view/base/web/template/form/element/color.html

```
<div class="swatches-visual-col col-default">
    <div class="swatch_window" style="background: #000000"
         data-bind="
         style: {'background-color': value},
         'aria-describedby': noticeId,
         id: uid, disabled: disabled,
         attr: {title: placeholder},
         hasFocus: focused
    "></div>
 </div>
```

> Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/form/element/pickcolors.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'mageUtils',
    'jquery',
    'jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker'
], function (Abstract, utils, $) {
    'use strict';
    return Abstract.extend({
        defaults: {
            placeholder: $.mage.__('Select Colors'),
            elementTmpl: 'Vendor_Module/form/element/color',
            links: {
                value: '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataScope }'
            }
        },
        /**
         * Calls 'initObservable' of parent
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('disabled visible value')
                .observe('addText');

            return this;
        },
        /**
         * Initializes regular properties of instance.
         *
         * @returns {Abstract} Chainable.
         */
        initConfig: function () {
            var uid = utils.uniqueid(),
                valueUpdate;
            this._super();
            valueUpdate = this.showFallbackReset ? 'afterkeydown' : this.valueUpdate;
            _.extend(this, {
                uid: uid,
                noticeId: 'notice-' + uid,
                valueUpdate: valueUpdate
            });
            console.log(this);
            return this;
        },
        /**
         * Initialize ColorPicker
         *
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        initColorPicker: function() {
            var self = this;
            $('[data-role="color-picker"]').ColorPicker({
                color: self.value(),
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(200);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(200);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex) {
                    $('#color-121').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                    self.userChanges();
                    self.value('#' + hex);
                    self.hasChanged();
                }
            });
            return false;
        },
        /**
         * Validates itself by it's validation rules using validator object.
         * If validation of a rule did not pass, writes it's message to
         * 'error' observable property.
         *
         * @returns {Object} Validate information.
         */
        validate: function () {
            var value   = this.value(),
                result  = this.checkColor(value),
                message = !this.disabled() && this.visible() ? result.message : '',
                isValid = this.disabled() || !this.visible() || result.passed;

            this.error(message);
            this.bubble('error', message);

            if (!isValid) {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', true);
            }

            return {
                valid: false,
                target: this
            };
        },
        checkColor: function(value) {
            var result = {message: $.mage.__('Color is not valid'), passed:false};
            if (/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(value)) {
                result = { message: '', passed: true };
            }
            return result;
        }
    });
});
```

**Please let me know if anyone has any idea.**

Comment: maybe this helps - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-colorpicker.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep only these files (remove the others from your example, you don't need them):

- Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml (unchanged)
- Vendor/Module/Ui/Modifier/Product/Style.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Modifier\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Style extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected ArrayManager $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager)
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        // Color attribute
        $code = 'my_color';
        $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($code, $meta, null, 'children');
        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(
            sprintf("%s%s", static::CONTAINER_PREFIX, $code),
            $meta,
            null,
            'children'
        );
        if (!$elementPath) {
            return $meta;
        }

        $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $containerPath,
            $meta,
            [
                'children' => [
                    $code => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'formElement' => 'colorPicker',
                                    'colorPickerMode' => 'full',
                                    'colorFormat' => 'hex',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```